# seg fault in an array of strings using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

What i am trying to do here is print all the elements of an array of strings,using pointers. The reason i dont use a counter is because i dont know the size of the array. I only know that it is always terminated with a null character. Running the code below gives me the elements until the last one("fri"). Then it gives me a segmentation fault. I cant really understand why. A little help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argv,char *argc[]){

    char *array[]={"mon","tue","wed","thu","fri",'\0'};
    char **parray;
    parray=array;
    char *pword;
    pword=&**parray;
    while (**parray != '\0'){
        printf("The first letter is %c\n",**parray);
        while (*pword != '\0'){
           printf("%c",*pword);
           pword++;
        }
        parray++;
        pword=&**parray;
     }
}
```

Comment: `&**` will only ever cause trouble.

Comment: `"fri",'\0'}` the type of your array is not consistent.

Comment: `while (**parray != NULL){` --> `while (*parray != NULL){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is a problem for the last element of `parray`.

```
while (**parray != '\0'){
```

For the last line, `*parray` is NULL. By using `**parray`, you are dereferencing a NULL pointer. Change that line to:

```
while (*parray != NULL){
```

I suggest changing the initialization to:

```
char *array[]={"mon","tue","wed","thu","fri",NULL};
```

That is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The last element is null character. Change `'\0'` to `"\0"`.

Answer (score 0):

The last value in array is zero - not a string containing a null.  So the test involving `**parray` is dereferencing that zero.  Either change the check to use `*parray` or change the last entry in array to be an empty string ("").